# Issue when submit app to apple store - "This bundle is invalid"

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode5

I got a message when upload app to apple store

```
This bundle is invalid. The value of the CFBundleDocumentTypes key in the Info.plist must be an array of dictionaries, with each dictionary containing at the least the CFBundleTypeName key. at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
```

This is my Info.plist file.

How to resolve my problem?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The error is correct. You don't have the `CFBundleTypeName` key for each document type. Instead of viewing the Info.plist like in the picture, in Xcode select your target and select the Info tab. Then go down to the Document Types section. For each document type, fill in the Name and Types. The rank should appear under the "Additional document type properties". There should be no extensions or roles listed for your Document Types.

Comment: Thank Mad, I just had fixed this issue.